# Como determinar o horario em que uma tarefa de segundo plano vai ser executada

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1, windows-10

Estou programando para Windows 10, e em determinado horário em um dia eu quero que minha tarefa em background seja deparada.

Aqui está meu código de registro:

na tela inicial:

```
var trigger = new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.TimeZoneChange, false);
            var condition = new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable);
            var tarefa = RegistrarTarefasSegundoPlanoAsync.RegisterBackgroundTask(typeof(SalvaImagemTask).FullName, "SalvaImagemTask", trigger, condition);
```

RegisterBackgroundTask.cs

```
public static BackgroundTaskRegistration RegisterBackgroundTask(
                                                string taskEntryPoint,
                                                string name,
                                                IBackgroundTrigger trigger,
                                                IBackgroundCondition condition)
        {

            foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                if (cur.Value.Name == name)
                {
                    return (BackgroundTaskRegistration)(cur.Value);
                }
            }


            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

            builder.Name = name;
            builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
            builder.SetTrigger(trigger);

            if (condition != null)
            {

                builder.AddCondition(condition);
            }

            BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();

            return task;
        }
```

aqui é como ela tá registrada no meu manifest

[image: Package.appxmanifest]

Comment: Creio que você possa usar a clase Time.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível determinar um horário especifico para uma background task ser executada. Você pode usar uma trigger de timer para especificar o intervalo de tempo entre as execuções da background task, respeitando o tempo minimo de 15 min, é uma regra. Segue exemplo de uso da trigger timer:

```
                BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
                taskBuilder.Name = nameof(BackgroundClassName);
                taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(BackgroundClassName).ToString();
                // min 15 minutes
                taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
                BackgroundTaskRegistration registration = taskBuilder.Register();
```

Se quiser ver outras triggers e como usar background tasks com eficiencia acesse esse MVA em portugues (https://mva.microsoft.com/pt-br/training-courses/live-tiles-e-background-execution-14433?l=K9L5uVmkB_1605192797)